# What UI elements (objects) are used in livingsocial iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, titanium

I am new to iPhone development. I am using Titanium for developing but I guess that hardly concerns my question.

What UI elements where used to develop the certain pages of livingsocial? There are hardly 5-6 windows in the whole app.

a) For eg: if you see the main page(daily deals,escapes,purchases,settings) - did they use a window with a black background image & then added tableview to it for the four options? each tableviewrow has different images. Is that how it could be done?

Also if you notice the four options are scrollable but the heading livingsocial stays static & looks different from the native UI. How was that done?

b) If you look at sign in page (in settings) - they have two textfields & a sign in button inside a window. For the last element (Don't have an account?), is that again a tableview inside a scrollableview?

It would be great if someone can give a general outline as to how they developed their app & what UI objects we used.

edit: please find the screen shots :
a)http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9556373/IMG_0616.PNG b)http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9556373/IMG_0620.PNG

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots?

Comment: Sure, a)http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9556373/IMG_0616.PNG b)http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9556373/IMG_0620.PNG

Comment: c) screenshot when you click on dailydeals http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9556373/IMG_0621.PNG

Answer (score 0):

> a) For eg: if you see the main page(daily deals,escapes,purchases,settings) - did they use a window with a black background image & then added tableview to it for the four options? each tableviewrow has different images. Is that how it could be done?
>   Also if you notice the four options are scrollable but the heading livingsocial stays static & looks different from the native UI. How was that done?

That app uses a custom made UINavigationController (for the static bar at the top, that can accommodate the title of the view and different buttons depending on the view currently showing, namely a back button for returning to the main view) and UITableView with custom made cells.

> b) If you look at sign in page (in settings) - they have two textfields & a sign in button inside a window. For the last element (Don't have an account?), is that again a tableview inside a scrollableview?

No, I think that's a UIButton, that just happens to look like an isolated cell. Also, that view doesn't look like its scrollable.

I'm not familiarized with Titanium, so I can't give you any directions there. But keep in mind that using custom controls usually takes more effort than simply using apple's own default.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your first question:

I'd use a tableview for that, with custom made cells to create that look. If it is not a main window on your tab you'll have to remove the 'back' button, otherwise it'll be fine.

In answer to your second question

The first 2 are textfields. The rest are all buttons (and the text above facebook button is a label).

If you're using titanium you could take a look at the [kitchensink example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9556373/IMG_0616.PNG).

Hope this helps!

Tjellekes